# Heads or tails game javascript do/while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, do-while, prompt

I am trying to make a basic heads or tails game using a do/while loop. My problem is that my prompts don't seem to influence my variables whatsoever as whatever I type it simply proceeds to the next section and then doesn't loop at all. Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

```
var userChoice;
var playAgain;

do {
    playAgain = prompt("Do you want to play Heads or tails?");
}
while (playAgain === "Yes") {
    userChoice = prompt("Choose Heads or Tails.");
    if (userChoice === "Heads") {
        coin = Math.random();
        if (coin <= 0.5) {
            console.log("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            console.log ("You lose");
        }
    }
    if (userChoice === "Tails") {
        coin = Math.random();
        if (coin > 0.5) {
            console.log("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("You lose");
        }
    }
    playAgain = prompt("Would you like to play again?");
};
```

Comment: Review the syntax of the `do-while` loop. Or, in your debugger, place a breakpoint on the `prompt` statement and step through your code to see what it is doing. Or, run a program like `jshint` over your code, and it will report `line 7, col 28, Missing semicolon.`, which should give you a clue as to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try like this instead:

```js
var userChoice;
var playAgain;

playAgain = prompt("Do you want to play Heads or tails?");

while (playAgain === "Yes") {
    userChoice = prompt("Choose Heads or Tails.");
    if (userChoice === "Heads") {
        coin = Math.random();
        if (coin <= 0.5) {
            alert("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            alert ("You lose");
        }
    } else if (userChoice === "Tails") {
        coin = Math.random();
        if (coin > 0.5) {
            alert("You Win!");
        }
        else {
            alert("You lose");
        }
    }
    playAgain = prompt("Would you like to play again?");
}
```

The do/while loop does the action under the `do` statement while the `while` condition is not met. Usually, you tend to avoid the do/while loop unless you REALLY need it, which is pretty rare.

Also, I replaced `console.log` to `window.alert` for the coherence and to avoid going to look at the console.

Comment: *The do/while loop does the action under the do statement while the while condition is not met.* To be precise, this should say *The do/while loop does the action under the do statement once, and then repeats it while the `while` condition is met.*

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the syntax of the `do-while` and `while` loops.

The `do-while` loop is

```
do { block } while (condition)
```

The `while` loop is

```
while (condition) { block }
```

You have tried to write a non-existent hybrid, of the form

```
do { block1 } while (condition) { block2 }
```

The JS parser will interpret this as:

```
do { block1} while (condition);
{ block2 }
```

where the semi-colon is inserted by the automatic semi-colon insertion mechanism. In other words, `block1` will continue to execute over and over again as long as `condition` is true. Then, and only then, will it proceed to execute `block2`.

You could have debugged this problem yourself by placing a breakpoint on the prompt statement and step through your code to see what it is doing.

Or, run a program like jshint over your code, and it will report

```
line 7, col 28, Missing semicolon
```

which would have given you a clue as to the problem.

The solution is to rewrite your code using correct syntax, most likely a plain old `while` loop.